# Override @active__color in theme

Tags: magento2, theme, less-css

I've defined `_theme_extend.less` and `_extend.less`. In `_theme_extend.less` I've had some success overriding values from the parent theme (in my case luma).

I have not been able to affect deeper changes though. I think if I could change something like `@active__color` defined in *./lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_colors.less* that would take care of a lot of variables I'd have to override individually.

I've been unable to override `@active__color` from my theme though. I tried creating `_colors_extend.less` and `@import _colors_extend.less` in `_extend.less`, however that doesn't do the trick. How can I override `@active_color`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your theme's `web/css/source/_extend.less` file:

`@active__color: @your-color;`

Confirmed to work in 2.1

Comment: Hi, Aaron, I may be looking in the wrong place, but I don't think this worked for me. I put `@active__color: green;` in `web/css/source/_extend.less` and still seeing the stock color (orange) which is defined in *_colors.less*.  I also ran `rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* var/view_preprocessed/ && ./bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` before looking for the change on the site.

Comment: These are the steps I take to ensure that a style change is being picked up: 1) delete contents of `pub/static` and `var/view_preprocessed` 2) Flush magento cache 3) Clear browser cache. I'm in developer mode so no need to deploy static content.

Comment: So it seems I'm confused as to what `@active__color` actually affects. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1):

Aaron perfect thanks! > `web/css/source/_extend.less`

```
@active_color: blue;
```

will change the accent colour (menu select colour) to blue

Note no @ symbol

Confirmed to work 2.2

make sure to flush static files cache.